# Optics - Derivation of Linear Magnification of Lens without Sign Convention

Tags: optics, lenses, conventions

In some posts in this forum I've read that sign convention in optics is useful for making formula memorizing easier, and that we have to use sign convention again while applying the formulae to neutralize the effect of taking sign convention... I tried to use geometry and saw that indeed without sign convention we get two formulae for lens maker's formula and so on... so in that way sign convention is useful... But i could not derive the formula for linear magnification by geometry - without sign convention the derivation does not match the formula given in the text books (which says m must be negative for convex lens when image is real). Can somebody please explain how to get it, and if not why don't we get it?

The Sign Convention used is:

1. The direction of the incident ray is positive.
2. Incident ray is always incident from the left side on the refracting surface.
3. Perpendicular distance of an object is positive when measured upwards from principal axis.
4. Distance is always taken FROM the pole of the refracting surface.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sign convention for mirror and lens formulas](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/113523/)

Comment: It is not a duplicate of that post... I am not asking WHY we use sign convention, but how to derive linear magnification formula only, without sign convention, just on the basis of geometry alone (not even using sign of tan x as per quadrants). I already know the purpose of sign convention.

Comment: For the derivation by similar triangles have a look at khanacademy.org. Physics > Waves > Object image heigt and distance relationship. The videos are both at the bottom.