# The equation governing lens systems

Tags: optics, conventions, lenses

In some sites, I find the lens equation to be (eg: [pg-6 of this pdf](https://www.plymouth.ac.uk/uploads/production/document/path/3/3754/PlymouthUniversity_MathsandStats_outreach_lenses.pdf)):

$$ \frac{1}{u} + \frac{1}{v} = \frac{1}{f}$$

And other sites I find it to be ([eg: 5:58 of this video](https://youtu.be/OYmVOkT4qIU?t=358)),

$$ \frac{1}{v} - \frac{1}{u} = \frac{1}{f}$$

So, which is correct lens equation/how are the two equations equivalent to each other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sign convention in optics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70730/)

Comment: Curious.  Your first reference says, "N.B. other sign conventions are sometimes used in the literature." But the reference DOES NOT give a sign convention!