# Variations of thin lens formula

Tags: optics, conventions, geometric-optics, lenses

I came across the thin lens formula online as:
$$\frac 1f = \frac 1v + \frac 1u $$
where f = focal length, v = distance of image, and u = distance of object

However, I noticed that the formula was taught differently in my textbook and I don't understand how both are correct.

[image]

Also, in most of the illustrations the image distance, which is assumed to be negative already, is once again entered as $-u$

[image]

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sign convention in optics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70730/)

Comment: Somewhat. Does that mean the only difference between these two is that in the second formula I need to use the signs based on the Cartesian plane?